# Telebot, python, в двух файлах .py, как объединить их работу?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Подскажите пожалуйста, не силен в telebot, увы(, учусь, возможно ли разнести бота в два и более .py модуля(файла). Например - есть основной файл main_test.py - в нем стартовое меню с кучей кнопок (в образце 2 кнопки - button и button_1, но их будет c пару дюжин). При нажатии любой из кнопок хотелось бы запускать свой .py файл со своими дальнейшими кнопками - запросами различных данных от пользователя (напр. дата рождения, локация, еще какие-то цифры (набор в каждой кнопке разный будет) и обрабатывающими их математически, и отдающими конечный результат, т.е. бот большой оч получается, большое количество разных меню/кнопок, сотни строк, путаница, поэтому хотелось бы разнести его функции в разные .py файлы.
В образце после вывода стартового меню - бот уходит на последний @bot.callback_query_handler (а он во втором файле) и больше не видит button который в main_test.py, кнопка button не работает, а button_1 (второй файл) - работает.
М.б есть какое-то решение, чтобы оба файла, все кнопки были рабочие всегда? Заранее благодарю за любую помощь!

main_test.py:

```
import mytoken
import telebot
import mod1_test  # импорт второго .py файла со своей структурой/кнопками и прочим.
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(mytoken.TOKEN)

mod1_test.register_commands(bot)  # знакомим бота с функцией во втором .py файле с кнопками

kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)  # стартовая клавиатура
bt = types.InlineKeyboardButton('button', callback_data='button')
bt1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('button_1', callback_data='button_1')
kb.add(bt, bt1)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])  # старт, получаем 2 кнопки - button и button_1
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Select:', reply_markup=kb)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data)
def otvet(callback):
    if callback.data == 'button':
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback.id)
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.id,
                              text='tut eschcho pusto')



bot.polling()
```

доп файл, mod1_test.py:

```
def register_commands(bot):
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data)
    def otvet_1(callback):
        if callback.data == 'button_1':
            bot.answer_callback_query(callback.id)
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.id,
                                  text='начинаем запрашивать данные от пользователя, обрабатывать их и даем результат обработки')
```

Answer (score 0):

Python предполагает возможность разделения на модули и подключения их.
В том числе, есть возможность подключения при выполнении какого-либо условия типа:

```
if a==b:
    import my_module
```

Сама эта команда равнозначна включению текста модуля в это место в коде с её выполнением после этого.

Вот простой пример сделал - попробуйте с ним поработать, меняя `a` и `b` в основном модуле:

```
# Это - основной модуль, при равенстве a и b подключит другой модуль
a=5
b=5

if a==b:
    import arifm
else:
    print ("no import")
```

```
# Это - модуль arifm.py
a=6
b=8

print('import successful: a+b=', a+b)
```

Comment: ммм...  т.е. применительно к моему коду в образце - {import mod1_test}  делаю не сразу (как это сейчас) а лишь по нажатию пользователем кнопки..  да, сейчас попробую переписать код

Comment: Можно и сразу сделать `import`, если ограничений нет. Я просто дал более сложный пример, отвечающий на ваш вопрос "При нажатии любой из кнопок хотелось бы запускать свой .py файл".

Comment: ну да, import работает конечно, но бот не получает ответ от нажатия кнопки по втором файле, затык именно в этом..  хэндлер во втором файле так не запускается(

Comment: Ясно, т.е. я ответил, как разнести на модули. Подозреваю на 99%, что иметь два работающих модуля надо через асинхронный режим, либо через многопочность, но так как боты не пишу, то не буду грузить более детальными догадками.

Comment: в  любом случае спасибо за помощь!